# Transaction stuck

Tags: spring, transactions

in my spring I defined insert* methods with their own transaction.
When I call one of those methods (let's call it `insertStackOverflow`) , this calls an external method (called `insertAndUpdateVersion`) which has its own annotation defined this way:
`@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)`.
It does an insert and then calls another method called `updateNoTransaction`. In this last method the transaction get stuck and I don't understand why. Some advices? Thanks

```
    MediaDocument mediaDocument=(MediaDocument)domainObject;
    String sql = "UPDATE "+DB.TB_DOCUMENTI_ALFRESCO+" SET " +
            "size = ?," +
            "data_modifica = ?," +
            "autore_modifica = ?," +
            "annullato = ?, " +
            "versione = ?, " +
            "bucket_name = ?, " +
            "object_name = ? " +
            "WHERE id = ?";

    FirmaUtil.settaDatiPerUpdate(mediaDocument);

    Object[] params = new Object[] { 
            mediaDocument.getFileSize(), 
            mediaDocument.getDataModifica(), 
            mediaDocument.getAutoreModificaId(),
            mediaDocument.isAnnullato(),
            mediaDocument.getMinioVersion(),
            mediaDocument.getMinioBucketName(),
            mediaDocument.getMinioIdSha(),
            mediaDocument.getPrimaryKey().getId()
    };

    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params);

    return mediaDocument;
```

Comment: Can you add the code for updateNoTransaction?

Comment: @Reg I added the code for updateNoTransaction